# how to split string into double and string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get  value from the following list box and separate the value into two double and int, and also a value from the combo box after getting these values i have to change these values into double and do some calculation on it and display the result in a message box. but it only display zero not whole value any solution pleas.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double Value;
    string[] value = listBox1.Text.Split('-');
    value[1] = value[1].Trim('$');
    double.TryParse(value[1] , out Value);
    double Cmbo;
    string cmboValue = comboBox1.Text;
    double.TryParse(cmboValue , out Cmbo);
    double final1 = Value * Cmbo;
    string final = final1.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(final);

}
```

[image]

Comment: What is value of comboBox1?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: `double Value;` is always 0 because you are not set value in that

Comment: @RAJNIKPATEL it will be set when parsing is successfully done : `double.TryParse(value[1] , out Value);`

Comment: What's the value of `comboBox1.Text`

Comment: Probably Amout value.

Comment: the values of combo are  1,2,3,4 etc. actually i am new in C#

Comment: show sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are splitting based on "-", why don't you use "$" and get your values:

```
string res = "Full dicorative-$50.00";
string splitString = res.Split('$')[1];
double Value;
Double.TryParse(splitString, out Value);
double Cmbo;
double.TryParse("50.00", out Cmbo);
double final1 = Value * Cmbo;
string final = final1.ToString();
```

It works perfectly.